# Wrong ordering items (fields) in JSON object in Swift

Tags: json, swift, xcode, dictionary, swift3

For example: I have a JSON like this:

```
{
    name : "Name",
    info: {
            info_one : "A",
            info_two : "B",
            info_three : "C" 
    }
}
```

When I got `info` item by `data["info"] as? [String:String]`, The result was wrong order. Like:

```
[("info_two":"B"), ("info_three":"C"), ("info_one":"A")]
```

How can I fix it? Please help me, thank you!

Comment: info is a dictionary and dictionary is order less.

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-c, Dictionary is order less.
But it`s depend on your requirement, follow it